# Is it possible for an HTTP `GET` request with `Cache-Control: no-cache` to not hit the server exactly once? (Levering out idempotency of `GET`.)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, networking, fetch

In theory, one should use the HTTP `GET` method only for idempotent requests.

But, for some intricate reasons, I cannot use any other method than `GET` and my requests are *not* idempotent (they mutate the database). So my idea is to use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to ensure that any `GET` request actually hits the database. Also, I cannot change the URLs which means I cannot append a random URL argument to bust caches.

Am I safe or shall I implement some kind of mechanism to ensure that the `GET` request was received exactly once? (The client is the browser and the server is Node.js.)

What about a `GET` request that gets duplicated by some middle-man resulting in the same `GET` request being received twice by the server? I believe the spec allows such situation but does this ever happen in "real life"?

I've never seen a middle man, such as Cloudflare or NGNIX, preventing or duplicating a `GET` request with `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Comment: A bit confused. Are you saying you want to ensure the server doesn't process the same request twice since its not an idempotent process? Or, are you worried that a browser or middleman would cache the result and not make the same request twice when you'd want it to?

Comment: I basically want to mutate the database with a `GET` request. Is it safe or not?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by saying what you've already pointed out -- GET requests **should** be idempotent. That is, they should not modify the resource and therefore should return the same thing every time (barring any other methods being used to modify it in the meantime.)

It's worth pointing out, as [restcookbook.com](https://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) notes, that this doesn't mean nothing can change as a result of the request. Rather, the resource's representation should not change. So for instance, your database might log the request, but shouldn't return a different value in the response.

The main concern you've listed is middleware caching.

The danger isn't that the middleware sends the request to your server more than once (you mentioned 'duplicating' a request), but rather that (a) it sends an old, cached, no-longer-accurate response to whatever is making the request, and (b) the request does not reach the server.

For instance, imagine a response returning a `count` property that starts at 0 and increments when the GET endpoint is hit. Request #1 will return "1" as the count. Request #2 should now return "2" as the count, but if its cached, it might still show as 1, and not hit the server to increase the count to 2. That's 2 separate problems you have (caching, and not updating).

So, *will* a middleware prevent a request from reaching the server and serve a cached copy instead? We don't know. It depends on the middleware. You can absolutely write one right now that does just that. You can also write one that doesn't.

If you don't know what will be consuming your API, then it's not a great option. But whether it's "safe" depends on the specifics.

As you know, it's always best to follow the set of expectations that comes with the grammar of HTTP requests. Deviating from them sets yourself up for failure in many ways. (For instance, there are different *security* expectations for requests based on method. A browser may treat a GET request as "simple" from a CORS perspective, while it would never treat a PATCH request as such.)

I would go to great lengths to not break this convention, but if I were forced by circumstances to break this expectation, I would definitely note it in my APIs documentation.

Comment: According to the spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4 `The "no-cache" request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use a stored response to satisfy the request without successful validation on the origin server.`. So all middle-man should forward the request to the server. Can I expect all middle-man to respect the spec? I guess so?

Comment: I agree that the spec suggests it should not be cached with that header (actually, cached is okay, but not using it without validating). However, this very question is a good example of specs not always being followed.

Comment: Interesting and good to know. Do you have an example of a middle-man not following the `no-cache` spec?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to ensure that your GET request is only called once is to allow caching of responses and use the **Vary** header. The spec for the Vary header can be [found here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4).

In summary, a Vary header basically tells any HTTP cache, which parts of the request header to take into account when trying to find the cached object.

For example, you have an endpoint `/api/v1/something` that accepts GET requests and does the required database updates. Let's say that when successful, this endpoint returns the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3458
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Vary: X-Unique-ID
```

Notice the Vary header has a value of `X-Unique-ID`. This means that if you include the `X-Unique-ID` header in your request, any HTTP caching layer (be it the browser, CDN, or other middleware) will use the value in this header to determine whether to use a previously cached response or not.

Say your make a first request that includes a `X-Unique-ID` header with the value `id_1` then you make a subsequent request with `X-Unique-ID` value of `id_2`. The caching layer will not use a previously cached response for the second request because the value of the `X-Unique-ID` is different.

However, if you make another request that contains the `X-Unique-ID` value of `id_1` again, the caching layer will not make a request to the backend but instead reuse the cached response for the first request assuming that the cache hasn't expired yet.

One thing you have to consider though is this will only work if the caching layer actually respects the specifications for the Vary header.

Comment: Neat, thanks. About `will only work if the caching layer actually respects the specification`: do caches usually respect the `Vary` header? E.g. all caches between a React Frontend and a Node.js app (Browser, service worker, cloudflare, server proxy, NGNIX, etc.)?

Comment: Good question. I know most browsers do and nginx can (if configured to do so). With regards to proxies, CDNs and other middle layer services that do some form of caching, some do and some don't unfortunately. So I guess this will only be a reliable option if you can confirm that it is supported by any of the layers your application will be using.

Comment: `some don't` do you have an example? I can't think of any internet middleman that wouldn't respect `Vary`.

Comment: I don't think cloudflare does... This article says "Cloudflare doesn't consider vary values when making caching decisions." - 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003206852

Comment: Didn't expect that... good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is designed to enable communications between clients and servers.
where Get method is used to request the data from specified resources.
When we used 'Cache-control: no-cache' it means the cache can't store anything about the client request
or server responses. That Request hits to the server and a full response is downloaded each and every time.

Comment: Yes that's what I would expect. But what about a single `GET` request being duplicated and received twice by the server? Welcome to SO btw.!

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on what's sat in the middle and where the retry logic sits, if there is any. Almost all of your problems will be in failure handling and retry handling - not the basic requests.

Let's say, for example that Alice talks to Bob via a proxy. Let's assume for the sake of simplicity that the requests are small and the proxy logic is pure store-and-forward. i.e. most of the time a request either gets through or doesn't but is unlikely to get stalled half-way through. There's no guarantee this is the case and some proxies will stop requests part-way through by design.

```
Alice -> Proxy GET
Proxy -> Bob GET
Bob -> Proxy 200
Proxy -> Alice 200
```

So far so good. Now imagine Bob dies before responding to the proxy. Does the proxy retry? If so, we have this:

```
Alice -> Proxy GET
Proxy -> Bob GET
Bob manipulates database then dies
Proxy -> Bob GET (retry)
Now we have a dupe
```

Unlikely, but possible.

Now imagine (much more likely) that the proxy (or even more likely, some bit of the network between the proxy and the client) dies. Does the client retry? If so, we have this:

```
Alice -> Proxy GET
Proxy -> Bob GET
Bob -> Proxy 200
Proxy or network dies
Alice -> Proxy GET (retry)
Proxy -> Bob GET
Is this a dupe or not? Depends on your point of view
```

Plus, for completeness there's also the degenerate case where the server receives the request zero times.

Comment: Are there actual proxies in the wild that do that? That re-requests a GET upon failure?

Comment: Not that I have direct experience of but a quick Google gave me this https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-layer-7-retries-and-chaos-engineering/ and I doubt it's unique

Comment: They have actually thought about this kind of situations and offer a opt-out option (`http-request disable-l7-retry`), e.g. for HTTP POST.

Comment: I'm actually starting to think that no proxy will ever do this kind of behavior. What I'm guessing here is there are a small but non-negligible amount of applications that do not respect the GET idempotence rule; if any proxy would introduce this kind of behavior then it would break all these apps. That forces all proxies to basically treat GET requests the same than POST requests. The whole POST/GET distinction is moot.